# NHibernate JoinQueryOver returns all subtype entries

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I know there are many similar topics but I couldn't find the answer I am searching for.

I have `Message` with list of `Receivers`. I am trying to get all messages with state `new` and receivers of type `A`. I get all messages having corresponding receivers but with all of their receivers. I only want to get the receivers I am interested in.

Here is what I am trying to use:

```
var messages = session.QueryOver<MessageDTO>()
    .Where(message => message.State == MessageState.New)
    .JoinQueryOver<MessageReceiverDTO>(message => message.MessageReceivers)
    .Where(receiver => receiver.Type == ReceiverType.A)
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
    .List();
    //.Where(message => message.MessageReceivers.Count > 0)
    //.ToList();
```

Would be great to have help with that. I also tried using `Select` for getting message and receiver out of the query but that didn't work neither.

Answer (score 0):

Try QueryOver with alias:

```
MessageDTO messageAlias = null;
MessageReceiverDTO receiverAlias = null;

var query =
    session.QueryOver<MessageDTO>(() => messageAlias)
         .JoinAlias(() => messageAlias.Receivers, () => receiverAlias)
         .Where(() => messageAlias.State == MessageState.New)
         .And(() => receiverAlias.Type == ReceiverType.A);
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* `Transformers.AliasToEntityMap` might be useful here. Basically it transforms each row in your resulting query to an `IDictionary` with keys corresponding to alias names and values corresponding to entities. For example:

```
MessageDTO message = null;
MessageReceiverDTO receiver = null;

var messages = session.QueryOver<MessageDTO>(() => messageAlias)
    .Where(message => message.State == MessageState.New)
    .JoinQueryOver<MessageReceiverDTO>(message => message.MessageReceivers, () => receiver)
    .Where(receiver => receiver.Type == ReceiverType.A)
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToEntityMap)
    .List<IDictionary>();

MessageDTO firstMessage = (MessageDTO)messages[0]["message"];
MessageReceiverDTO firstReceiver = (MessageReceiverDTO)messages[0]["receiver"];
```